# Cannot set the value of read-only property 'group' for DefaultExternalModuleDependency

Tags: android, gradle

I am solving duplicate issue due build process caused by a new library. There are some duplicate classes or a whole package of `bouncycastle`. The issue is the default way to exclude a class or a whole group brings this issue:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Cannot set the value of read-only property 'group' for DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='org.web3j', name='core', version='4.8.7-android', configuration='default'} of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultExternalModuleDependency
```

Code itself:

```
implementation('org.web3j:core:4.8.7-android') {
    exclude(group = 'org.bouncycastle')
}
```

Is there some changes in exclude usage over the past few years?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's just a syntax issue, the `exclude` method expects a `Map` parameter. it looks like you are using the Groovy DSL, and in Groovy maps are created using `:`  character ( in Kotlin DSL you would use `=` as you did)

So just replace `=` assignement by `:` as follows:

```
    implementation('org.web3j:core:4.8.7-android') {
        exclude(group : 'org.bouncycastle')
    }
```

See some examples here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:excluding-transitive-deps

Comment: Thank you for addressing this. Android Studio by default uses Groovy DSL (build.gradle instead of build.gradle.kts) and Kotlin DSL was out of my attention.