# Custom gradle configuration does not let me declare a dependency with exclusions

Tags: gradle, dependencies

Given this very simple gradle file, declaring a [custom configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sec:defining-custom-configurations) `myConf` and setting a dependency on this configuration:

```
configurations {
    myConf
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    myConf("commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.4")
}
```

When I run `gradle dependencies` and I get:

```
> Task :dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project 'tmp-project'
------------------------------------------------------------

myConf
\--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.4
     +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
     \--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2

A web-based, searchable dependency report is available by adding the --scan option.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Everything works as expected.

Next I try to define an exclusion on the `commons-beanutils` dependency (from the docs [Excluding transitive dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:excluding-transitive-deps))

```
configurations {
    myConf
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    myConf("commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.4") {
        exclude(group = "commons-collections", module = "commons-collections")
    }
}
```

I now get following error when running `gradle dependencies`

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/__path-to-tmp-project__/build.gradle' line: 11

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'tmp-project'.
> Cannot set the value of read-only property 'group' for DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='commons-beanutils', name='commons-beanutils', version='1.9.4', configuration='default'} of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultExternalModuleDependency.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: The answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73888147/91497 (mine is a duplicate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `exclude(group: "commons-collections", module: "commons-collections")`

Looks like you are mixing up the Kotlin syntax with the Groovy one ;)

Comment: Exactly! copy pasted from the wrong tab in the docs...