A problem occurred evaluating project ':pdf_viewer_plugin'
I'm trying to run my flutter app on a device connected through USB, and there's the error message showing up:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/USER/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/pdf_viewer_plugin-2.0.1/android/build.gradle' line: 39

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':pdf_viewer_plugin'.
> Cannot set the value of read-only property 'force' for DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='com.github.barteksc', name='android-pdf-viewer', version='3.0.0-beta.4', configuration='default'} of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultExternalModuleDependency.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 3m 53s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            233,7s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I recently updated my Flutter and Android Studio, here is the flutter doctor output:
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 3.27.0-0.2.pre, on macOS 15.1.1 24B91 darwin-arm64, locale pt-BR)
    • Flutter version 3.27.0-0.2.pre on channel beta at /Users/USER/Documents/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision fc011960a2 (3 weeks ago), 2024-11-14 12:19:18 -0800
    • Engine revision 397deba30f
    • Dart version 3.6.0 (build 3.6.0-334.4.beta)
    • DevTools version 2.40.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/USER/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-35, build-tools 35.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-79915917-b509.11)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 16.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 16B40
    • CocoaPods version 1.16.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-79915917-b509.11)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.95.3)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.102.0

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    • POCOPHONE F1 (mobile)           • android-arm64  • Android 10 (API 29)
    • macOS (desktop)                 • darwin-arm64   • macOS 15.1.1 24B91 darwin-arm64
    • Mac Designed for iPad (desktop) • darwin         • macOS 15.1.1 24B91 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)                    • web-javascript • Google Chrome 131.0.6778.86

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

Does anyone have any idea how to fix the error?
I already tried to clear ~/.gradle folder and run flutter clean command.

The error message refers to build.gradle line 39, while that flutter doctor output is entirely irrelevant. This appears to be similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883761
